# How do I build sqlcipher.. mingw

Tags: sqlite, mingw, sqlcipher

I'm korean. I'm using a translator.
So, even if the grammar is awkward, please understand.

I built sqlcipher by referring to "http://www.jerryrw.com", 
I created an exe file.but while building, There was a warning.

```
$ make
./libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC gcc -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL -I/c/opensslbuild32/include /c/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll -L/c/sqlcipher/ -static-libgcc -DSQLITE_OS_WIN=1 -I. -I/c/sqlcipher/src -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/rtree -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/icu -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/fts3 -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/async -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/session -D_HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H -DBUILD_sqlite -DNDEBUG  -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1    -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=1 -c sqlite3.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL -I/c/opensslbuild32/include /c/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll -L/c/sqlcipher/ -static-libgcc -DSQLITE_OS_WIN=1 -I. -I/c/sqlcipher/src -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/rtree -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/icu -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/fts3 -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/async -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/session -D_HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H -DBUILD_sqlite -DNDEBUG -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=1 -c sqlite3.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/sqlite3.o
sqlite3.c: In function 'sqlcipher_cipher_profile':
sqlite3.c:21289:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fopen_s' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if(fopen_s(&f, destination, "a") != 0){
        ^~~~~~~
gcc.exe: warning: c:/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

and sqlcipher.exe does not  seem to work well.
After running the executable, I got the following output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67qeS.png)

Please help me build sqlcipher properly.

once again,I'm using a translator...
Please understand...

Comment: Please cut and paste the text of the output into the question rather than linking to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

From the image (which you should have included in the text of your question), it looks like you encrypted your database with a key but did not supply that key when you subsequently opened it, so of course the encrypted database was unreadable.

In other words, when you open your database after having created it with a key, the *first* thing you must do is issue:

```
PRAGMA key = '....';
```

Comment: hello!
Thank you for answer.
but, I knew what you answered.
When the PRAGMA key is not entered, I want to know if this sentence is right. —>“files is not a database”.
Because I encrypted it.I think the results are different from others.---->"files is encrypted or files is not a database "
So,I think the build did not work.
also, Can I ignore warnings?
“gcc.exe: warning: c:/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll: linker input file unused because linking not done”
I’m wondering if the openssl library was properly linked and built.
I wonder warning....thank you!